# create txt file list from php

Tags: php, windows, text, xampp

I have bunch of images file (.jpg) in a folder, then I want to list them to a single file text, I using php (xampp in windows).

This for list images name in my browser (it's working):

```
<?php
ob_start();
$file='F:\images\upload\google\ready_45';
     foreach (glob($file."\*.jpg") as $filenames) {
          echo $filenames."<br />";
     }
?>
```

This for create text file called 'images_list.txt' (not working):

```
<?php
ob_start();
$file='F:\images\upload\google\ready_45';
     foreach (glob($file."\*.jpg") as $filenames) {
       $my_file = 'image_list.txt';
       $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
       $data = echo $filenames."<br />";
       fwrite($handle, $data);
     }
?>
```

When I execute that script, appear warning message

"
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in D:\xampp\htdocs\rename_file_php\try_list_img.php on line 7"

If line 7, I change

```
       $data = $filenames;
```

The file 'images_list.txt' will created, but only fill one image name listing in the file. Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open file once and try to write data once:-

```
<?php
ob_start();
$file='F:\images\upload\google\ready_45';
$data = '';
foreach (glob($file."\*.jpg") as $filenames) {
    $data .= $filenames."\n";
}
$my_file = 'image_list.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);  
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Comment: @Ben...  glad to help you.:)

Answer (score 1):

You want to fopen() the file only once, so outside the loop. Otherwise you overwrite the content again and again. Take a look at this modified version:

```
<?php
$folder = 'F://images/upload/google/ready_45';
$my_file = 'image_list.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die("Cannot open file: ". $my_file);
foreach (glob($folder . "/*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $data = $filename . PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($handle, $data);
}
fclose($handle);
```

One certainly could simplify that. For example by simply imploding the list of matched file names with a linebreak and then writing the result in one go:

```
<?php
$folder = 'F://images/upload/google/ready_45';
$data = implode(PHP_EOL, glob($folder . "/*.jpg"));

$my_file = 'image_list.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die("Cannot open file: ". $my_file);
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
```

However the first (loop based) approach allows more flexibility, for example filtering or escaping.

---

Side notes:

- using a normal slash as folder delimiter (`/`) instead of the insane backslash (`\\`) natively used in MS-Windows will save you a lot of hassle. PHP can work with both on a MS-Windows platform.
- using a line break instead of the html linewrap makes more sense when writing into a file in most cases. Using `PHP_EOL` instead of a hard coded line break (`\r\n`) will make your code portable for systems using different types of line breaks (only MS-Windows uses `\r\n` for that).
- I took the liberty to also fix some indentation and code styling issues. It definitely makes sense if programmers loosely agree on some standard to enhance readability of code.

Comment: Thanks, I use `\n` for create a new line

Comment: Sure, if you are creating the file to be exclusively used in unixoid environments (so Linux), that is fine. You may want to define a constant for that though.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
// Creates a newline separated list from the array returned by glob()
$files = glob ($folder.'/*.jpg');
$files = implode (PHP_EOL, $files);

∕∕ This is all that is needed to write something to a file.
file_put_contents ($my_file, $files);
```

The `fopen()` and all that is old, old code, which should be avoided whenever possible. Not only is this method simpler and easier to read, but it's also generally faster.
Note that you might want to wrap an IF statement around the last line, in order to handle any errors with writing that might crop up.

Comment: only for new php version or can use in all version ? my xampp version is 1.7.3

Comment: If you check the PHP manual for `file_put_contents()` you'll see that it requires PHP 5, and up. I don't know exactly which version is in that xampp version, but unless it's about a decade old it should have a 5.x version of PHP.
http://php.net/file_put_contents

Answer (score -1):

Following code is working fine, I have a images folder which is having some image files, please change the folder path and try the below code

```
   <?php
    ob_start();
    $file='images';
    foreach (glob($file."\*.jpg") as $filenames) {
    $my_file = 'image_list.txt';
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
    $data = $filenames."\r\n";
    fwrite($handle, $data);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This may work, but it is extremely inefficient... You still open the file again and again in each loop iteration. Also the terminating php tag (`?>`) is generally considered bad style, since it _may_ cause huge issues and is not required at all.